# In SendEmail MSGRAPH API InternalServerError,Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net-core, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

Tried to use Microsoft Graph Email API, BUT getting following error.

**ODATA Payload**

```
"message": {
"subject": "Send email",
"body": {
"contentType": "text",
"content": "wuirbmndf"
},
"toRecipients": [
{
"emailAddress": {
"address": "emailid"
}
}
],
"attachments": [
{
"@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
"name": "attachment.txt",
"contentType": "text/plain",
"contentBytes": "SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh"
}
],
"from": {
"emailAddress": {
"address": "sender email id"
}
}

}
```

**My Code Looks Like ->**

```
client.BaseUrl = new Uri(String.Format("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendmail"));
RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
request.Method = Method.POST;
request.AddParameter("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer " + emailObj.AccessToken), ParameterType.HttpHeader);
request.AddParameter("application/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);
//request.AddHeader("ContentType", "application/json");
//request.JsonSerializer.ContentType = "string";

var result = client.Execute(request);
```

And I am Getting InternalServerError with error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
    {
  "error": {
    "code": "InternalServerError",
    "message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "22ec4d88-2140-497f-bf28-80c83d7aa6a9",
      "date": "2020-05-27T04:24:14"
    }
  }
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried same payload in ms graph explorer and it working fine for me (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer). I changed only email addresses.

Comment: Hi Manish, Same Payload is working in Postman as well but when integrated with backend in c# its giving the mentioned error message.

Comment: can you check the bearer token then, might be an expired token or something else.

Comment: yes tried using new token as well but same error, if it would have token related issue the error message shows the authentication related error message

Comment: have you tried using graph sdk? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-3

Comment: I tried using your code, and it's working for me, https://gist.github.com/manishtiwari25/f94cb1c70e085700d08828c90a1a6eb0 but I used the token from Graph Explorer.

Comment: Hi Manish, Yeah that 1 works but the message Json i will receive it from the UI then how will i receive the message json as a input in API

Comment: didn't get you, correct me if I am wrong, you are saying whole message payload will come from the UI so for that Either you can create a model for it or just receive it as an string.

Comment: Yes as i am developing the api based app whole payload will going to come from UI side and corresponding model i have created and assigning  the payload to model and converting it into json and passing to sendEmail api which is giving me object reference error, I have converted the above json into c# class using https://www.jsonutils.com/

Comment: I have updated my code, https://gist.github.com/manishtiwari25/f94cb1c70e085700d08828c90a1a6eb0

Comment: Let me know if it's working

Comment: Tried the above and now getting error{
  "error": {
    "code": "RequestBodyRead",
    "message": "The property 'Type' does not exist on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.Attachment'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type or mark the type as open type.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "da546d0f-1af6-4cf8-9ac1-3a89432bca53",
      "date": "2020-05-29T06:51:33"
    }
  }
}

Comment: The attachment type in your code is incorrect or null, can you debug it and tell me please

Comment: Hi Manish , I  am  using the same code you provided and getting same error